# What is the Lorenz condition for potentials?

Tags: electromagnetism, gauge-theory, gauge

I was just going through the "Electromagnetic Waves" chapter in the Classical Field Theory book by Landau. Here he mentions that they impose an auxiliary condition and it is known as the [Lorenz condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_gauge_condition) for potentials. If someone could explain intuitively why we're doing this, it'll be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of the Lorenz gauge is to have a gauge condition that is Lorentz (sic!) invariant.

Since the Lorenz gauge condition is $\partial^\nu A_\nu = 0$ and the left hand side is a scalar (since it is a contraction over 4-vectors), the condition is left invariant under Lorentz transformations. The Lorenz gauge condition then simplifies equations (e.g. we get the wave equation for $A^\nu$ by gauging away a term $\partial^\nu A_\nu$). The Lorenz condition does, however, not uniquely determine the gauge (since two components of $A^\nu$ may be chosen arbitrarily by the gauge).

Comment: Generally this is correct, however the last sentence is not. Lorentz transformations won't change the gauge. Lorentz transformations are a space-time symmetry which is independent of the gauge set for the EM field, it corresponds to a $U(1)$ symmetry. (already edited)

Answer (score 1):

You asked for an intuitive explanation, so the basic idea is that because B is the curl of the vector potential A, then you can add the gradient of any function to A without changing B.   $$A \rightarrow A + \nabla \psi$$

If you add such a gradient, then you'll find (by plugging into Maxwell) that in order for E to remain the same you need to transform the scalar potential via $$\phi \rightarrow \phi - \partial_t \psi$$

The bottom line is that E and B will remained unchanged for any function $\psi(x,t)$ if you transform the potentials according to the two equations above.   The Lorenz condition you refer to is just one particularly convenient choice.  But different problems can be simplified by [appropriate choice of this gauge.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_fixing)  Since there are arbitrarily many different choices of the gauge function $\psi$, this illustrates a fundamental symmetry $U(1)$ of electrodynamics.

Answer (score 0):

You asked WHY they imposed the Lorenz condition? 
They did it to simplify the equations they had derived to that point, leading to wave equations for the potentials.